# Advanced Search Scope set to multiple mailboxes

Tags: vba, outlook

I cannot find an example online of the syntax to do the advance search function in vba with the scope set to multiple mailboxes. Is there a way to do this or can you only search on a single mailbox and if you can what does the syntax look like? I have a scope variable setup like this.

```
Scope = "'" & OutApp.Session.Folders("sharemailbox@abc.com").FolderPath & "'"
```

However, i need to search on this mailbox and on othersharedmailbox@abc.com also so I was thinking maybe there is a way to do a union of two folders or something? Also, if there is a method as well to search all mailboxes in outlook as well because i may use that down the line as well. ANy help is appreciated as this is the last item to finishing my code!

Answer (score 0):

You must run separate search processes for each store.

Using the `Scope` parameter, you can specify one or more folders in the same store, but you may not specify multiple folders in multiple stores. To specify multiple folders in the same store for the Scope parameter, use a comma character between each folder path and enclose each folder path in single quotes. For default folders such as Inbox or Sent Items, you can use the simple folder name instead of the full folder path. For example, the following two lines of code represent valid Scope parameters:

```
Scope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items'"
```

or

```
Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath _  
    & "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"
```

For example, a use-case may look like this:

```
Public blnSearchComp As Boolean  

Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)  
    Debug.Print "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired"  
    If SearchObject.Tag = "Test" Then  
        m_SearchComplete = True  
    End If  

End Sub  

Sub TestAdvancedSearchComplete()  
    Dim sch As Outlook.Search  
    Dim rsts As Outlook.Results  
    Dim i As Integer  
    blnSearchComp = False  
    Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'"  
    Const strS As String = "Inbox"     
    Set sch = Application.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF, "Test")   
    While blnSearchComp = False  
        DoEvents  
    Wend   
    Set rsts = sch.Results  
    For i = 1 To rsts.Count  
        Debug.Print rsts.Item(i).SenderName  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Finally, you may find the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article helpful.

Comment: So a store is a seperate mailbox? For instance when I log into outlook i see multiple shared mailbox addresses. Each one represents its own store?